# No tag "choose" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm using java server pages for the first time and I'm having a problem with tags.  I am also working in Eclipse, if that's relevant.

The specific error I'm getting is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Query.jsp (line: 5, column: 0) No tag "choose" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"
```

The problem is, there *is* a tag "choose" with a prefix c...

I was having trouble with the urls that are usually recommended, it seems some of them are outdated, so I downloaded the standard tags and extracted them into my WEB-INF/tags directory.

My jsp file starts out with:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" import="beans.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/c.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/sql.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/fn.tld" %>    
<c:choose>
....
```

c.tld has:

```
...
<tag>
    <description>
        Simple conditional tag that establishes a context for
        mutually exclusive conditional operations, marked by
        &lt;when&gt; and &lt;otherwise&gt;
    </description>
    <name>choose</name>
    <tag-class>org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ChooseTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
</tag>
```

It's my guess that there's some sort of configuration error somewhere, but I'm totally clueless about where it might be.

Comment: Please put your mouse above the `[jstl]` tag below the question until a box pops up and then click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your taglib declarations are wrong.  Replace this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/c.tld" %>
```

with this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and make sure it's *not* (as some ancient tutorials say):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
```

... and repeat for the other libraries. You don't need your own copies of the `.tld` files, they're no longer required.

> I was having trouble with the urls that are usually recommended, it seems some of them are outdated

I'm not sure where you got that from, but almost any JSP/servlet engine will work with the URIs I mentioned. If those URIs *don't* work, then post a new question to that effect.  Downloading your own `tld` files is almost certainly not the correct approach.

Comment: I made that change and now I'm getting `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` 
I think the 'cannot be resolved' bit was why I thought they were outdated.  I've found something about versions that might be the key, but any other advice is welcome!  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't change the taglib URI from the one as skaffman included in his answer.

Comment: @usmcs: `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` isn't what I said; please read the answer.

Comment: @skaffman Oops! My mistake.  I've fixed the url, but I'm still getting the same "not resolved" problem, but I think that's for a question for another post after I look into it some.  Thanks!